# White color issue for JPEG remote images on Android

Tags: android, image, titanium, titanium-alloy

Since January 2011, we are using Appcelerator Titanium framework for our Android app.
We recently decided to improve our "home" listView.

Now, each row of this listView contains an imageView with a remote JPEG image.
The white background color of the remote images is not perfectly displayed as white.
The background color of the asset is #FFFFFF but once displayed in the app the color is diplayed as #F9FDF8 - see the screenshot below -.

[image: bad white background]

There is no issue for our iOS app using the same code.

Anybody know how to solve that?
Are we missing something in the Android configuration?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this issue, I am facing the same issue